# Python- Dot Product of a Slice of Row of Matrix with Slice of a Vector

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to write a simple code for Gaussian Elimination.

```
import numpy as np

def g_elimination(A,B):
    n=A.shape[0]
    for i in range(0,n-1):# Pivot Rows where 1st pivot is Row 0
        for j in range(i+1,n):#Rows to transform exclude Row 0
            B[j]=B[j]-(A[j,i]/A[i,i])*B[i]
            A[j]=A[j]-np.dot(A[j,i]/A[i,i],A[i])


def back_substitution(X,A,B):
    n=B.shape[0]
    for i in reversed(range(0,n)): 
        X[i]=(B[i]-np.dot([X[:i]],A[i:,:i]))/A[i,i]



A=np.array([[4.0,-2,1],[-2,4,-2],[1,-2,4]])
B=np.array([11,-16,17],dtype='float64')
X=np.zeros(B.shape)

g_elimination(A,B)
back_substitution(X,A,B)
```

During the back substitution phase, I am trying to find the dot product of the slice of row of matrix
A with slice of vector X. I am getting an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 25, in <module>
    back_substitution(X,A,B)
  File "main.py", line 16, in back_substitution
    X[i]=(B[i]-np.dot([X[:i]],A[i:,:i]))/A[i,i]
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in dot
ValueError: shapes (1,2) and (1,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Could anyone please help me correct this error.

Comment: `[X[:i]]` - why the brackets around this term for `np.dot`

Comment: wwii - Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed that error.

Answer (score 0):

> help me correct **this** error.

For the example data you gave, the terms of `np.dot` end up being 1d and 2d, if you switch them around `np.dot(2d,1d)` that error goes away. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with your calc/process so I don't really know if this is what you want. Since one of the terms is 1d I wonder whether you intended it to be a scalar.

```
def back_substitution(X,A,B):
    n=B.shape[0]
    for i in reversed(range(0,n)):
        #X[i]=(B[i]-np.dot([X[:i]],A[i:,:i]))/A[i,i]
        q = X[:i]
        r = A[i:,:i]
        s = A[i,i]
        t = B[i]
        try:
            #u = np.dot([q],r)
            #u = np.dot(q,r)
            #u = np.dot(r,q)
            little,big = sorted([q,r],key=lambda w: w.ndim)
            u = np.dot(big,little)
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
            print(q)
            print(r)
            print(q.shape,r.shape)
            print('*****')
        v = (t-u)/s
        X[i] = v
        #print(X)
```

This gets rid of the *original* ValueError that you asked about - but now `X[i] = v` complains that you are trying to set an array element with a sequence. Again being unfamiliar with what you are trying to do, I don't know what the solution is.